# How do I brand sms sent via kannel and nexmo

Tags: sms, smpp, kannel, vonage

I'm working on configuring kannel to send smses via kannel. I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically change the sender id with each sender message i.e If the message is from customer care then on the clients handset it should read from:XYZCustomerCare if its from billing then it should read from:XYZBilling.
From the research I've done so far I've found a little configuration option known as source_addr googling it I found a rather disturbing link to a paper on sms fraud from gsma. My quesion then is how do I control the value of th senders address while sending mesdsages via kannel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your operator allows alpha numeric IDs (whose max is around 11 xters), then there is no problem. The "to" field can have "customercare" as the sender ID. The message will go through without an issue and the subscriber will receive it. Kannel doesn't have a restriction.